# Validation of method in .cs file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, methods

net... 
I'm making a simple MVC project with the help of tutorial in given link:

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/486161/Creating-a-simple-application-using-MVC
```

I'm getting error at this particular stage.

Now let’s apply validations on the fields:

```
Error   2   The type or namespace name 'DisplayName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   
C:\Users\sword\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyCalculatorSrevice\MyMvc1\MyMvc1\Models\UserModels.cs
```

I searched for it, but couldn't find anything to remove this error.

help me out

thanx

Comment: Have you added a reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, sound like the Display attribute is missing

Comment: I know you have pointed to the code, but a small snippet of the code would make it easer for those here to assist - without first going elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure  :

1. You've referenced  System.ComponentModel assembly
2. You have import the annotation by `using  System.ComponentModel;` in your UserModel.cs file.

Hope it will help u,

Answer (score 0):

you are actually missing reference to `DataAnnotations`. Try adding following line at among references, and it will start working.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```